# Implementing reusable lifecycle behavior

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to implement reusable lifecycle behavior in svelte components. The idea is to implement a module to perform something when lifecycle methods of a component occur. This module would then be imported in svelte components easily. I thought about the following:

Imagine I have several components and I want to log something when onMount and onDestroy occur, so I could just repeat the following code in each component:

```
// Hello.svelte
<script>
import {onMount, onDestroy} from 'svelte';
onMount(()=>{
  console.log('Mounted!')
});
onDestroy(()=>{
  console.log('Destroyed!')
});

</script>
<h1>Hello World!<h1/>
```

But, in order to make this reusable I want to isolate this behavior in a module. The way I came up with is the following:

```
//appendLogger.js
export default (onMount,onDestroy)=>{
  onMount(()=>{
  console.log('Mounted!')
});
  onDestroy(()=>{
    console.log('Destroyed!')
  });
};
```

And in the components I could use it like this:

```
//Hello.svelte
<script>
import {onMount, onDestroy} from 'svelte';
import appendLogger from '../appendLogger';
appendLogger(onMount,onDestroy);
</script>
<h1>Hello World!<h1/>
```

and

```
//Goodbye.svelte
<script>
//Hello.svelte
import {onMount, onDestroy} from 'svelte';
import appendLogger from '../appendLogger';
appendLogger(onMount,onDestroy);
</script>
<h1>Goodbye World!<h1/>
```

Now is this approach correct ? 
Is there a better way to achieve this?
What are the caveats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onMount` and `onDestroy` are just functions — you can call them from anywhere, you don't need to pass them around. The only requirement is that you call them while the component is initialising, so that they are 'linked' to the component.

Which means you can create a helper function like this...

```js
// log.js
import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte';

export default function log() {
  onMount(() => {
    console.log('mounted');
  });

  onDestroy(() => {
    console.log('destroyed');
  });
});
```

...and call it inside your component like any other function:

```html
<script>
  import log from './log.js';
  log();
</script>
```

Note that if you return a function from `onMount`, that function will be called at the same time as `onDestroy`, so you can simplify it further:

```js
// log.js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export default function log() {
  onMount(() => {
    console.log('mounted');
    return () => console.log('destroyed');
  });
});
```

Here's a demo: https://svelte.dev/repl/e19cfcfcd3824f5d87aaae7673061021?version=3.5.1

Comment: Thanks Rich... That's awesome. Pretty powerfull stuff. I'm not sure if it's on the docs, but should be if not.